# Can I send a curl request without content-length?

Tags: curl, content-length

I tried multile ways to send a post request using curl without curl but I am getting the header.

Method1:

```
curl --ignore-content-length --request PUT somehttps-domain/ignored-content-length.txt --upload-file ignored-content-length.txt -kv (I m getting actual content length at server side)
```

Method 2

```
curl --request PUT somehttps-domain/ignored-content-length.txt --upload-file ignored-content-length.txt --header 'Content-Lenght:' -kv (I m getting content length as zero at server side)
```

I dont want this header at server side. If I dont add also curl is adding by default.

Any suggestions??

Comment: `--ignore-content-length` is for when receiving the response. I think curl will leave it out when sending if you use the header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"

Answer (score 0):

to force curl to not add a content-length to it's upload request (not sure why anyone would ever want to do that...), add

```
-H "Content-Length:"
```

to tell curl to *ignore* the content-length header it receives from the server (useful for bugged servers sending incorrect Content-Length headers), add

```
--ignore-content-length
```

Comment: Thank you.. I tried this but the header was still coming with content-length : 0. As mentioned in the above comment we have to include Transfer-Encoding: chunked in the header.

Comment: curl 8.4.0 on Windows will not sent the content-length header using -H "Content-Length:"